# Integral of $x^2dx$ by definition - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

$$\int_a^bx^2dx$$

By definition

$$b-a=nh$$
$$\lim_{h\to0}a^2h+(a+h)^2h+(a+2h)^2h+...+(a+(n-1)h)^2h$$
$$\lim_{h\to0}h(a^2+(a+h)^2+(a+2h)^2+...+(a+(n-1)h)^2)$$
$$\lim_{h\to0}h(a^2+(a^2+1^2h^2+2*1h)+(a^2+2^2h^2+2*2h)+...+(a^2+(n-1)^2h^2+2*(n-1)h))$$
$$\lim_{h\to0}h(na^2 + (1^2+2^2+...+(n-1)^2)h^2+(2*1+2*2+...+2*(n-1))h)$$
$$\lim_{h\to0}nha^2+\lim_{h\to0}h^3(1^2+2^2+...+(n-1)^2)+\lim_{h\to0}2h^2(1+2+...+(n-1))$$
$$(b-a)a^2+\lim_{h\to0}h^3n\frac{(n-1)(2n-1)}{6}+\lim_{h\to0}h^2n(n-1)$$
$$(b-a)a^2+\frac{1}{6}\lim_{h\to0}nh\lim_{h\to0}h^2(2n^2+3n+1)+\lim_{h\to0}nh\lim_{h\to0}nh-h$$
$$(b-a)a^2+\frac{1}{6}(b-a)\lim_{h\to0}(2(nh)^2+3nh^2+h^2)+(b-a)(\lim_{h\to0}nh-\lim_{h\to0}h)$$
$$(b-a)(a^2+\frac{1}{6}\lim_{h\to0}(2(nh)^2+3nh^2+h^2)+(\lim_{h\to0}nh-\lim_{h\to0}h))$$
$$(b-a)(a^2+\frac{1}{6}(2\lim_{h\to0}(nh)^2+3\lim_{h\to0}nh\lim_{h\to0}h+\lim_{h\to0}h^2)+((b-a)-0))$$
$$(b-a)(a^2+\frac{1}{6}(2(b-a)^2+3(b-a)*0 + 0)+(b-a))$$
$$(b-a)(a^2+\frac{1}{6}2(b-a)^2+(b-a))$$
$$(b-a)(a^2+\frac{1}{3}(b-a)^2+(b-a))$$
$$(b-a)(\frac{3a^2+(b-a)^2+(b-a)}{3})$$
$$(b-a)(\frac{3a^2+b^2+a^2-2ab+b-a}{3})$$
$$\frac{(b-a)}{3}(4a^2+b^2-2ab+b-a)$$
which is not equal to $$\frac{b^3-a^3}{3}$$ for this to happen the fraction should have been  $$\frac{(b-a)}{3}(b^2+a^2+ab)$$

Please tell me where did I go wrong

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is unreadable.

Comment: From your 3rd line after "By definition", check how you expanded $(a+ih)^2$ (for $i\in\mathbb Z$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Please tell me where did I go wrong

$$\lim_{h\to0}a^2h+(a+h)^2h+(a+2h)^2h+...+(a+(n-1)h)^2h$$
$$\lim_{h\to0}h(a^2+(a+h)^2+(a+2h)^2+...+(a+(n-1)h)^2)$$
$$\lim_{h\to0}h(a^2+(a^2+1^2h^2+2*1h\color{red}{*a})+(a^2+2^2h^2+2*2h\color{red}{*a})+...+(a^2+(n-1)^2h^2+2*(n-1)h\color{red}{*a}))$$

Comment: Thanks .... A lot !! you just saved the day